# How to export posebone location, rotation and scaling including IK?

Tags: python, export, bones, pose-mode, matrix

Not sure if that is a perfect title, I'm doing a mesh skinning shader in Game Maker and it is done, both the model and bones are exported from Blender (after struggling making an exporter)

My problem comes when writting an exporter for the animations (I could animate it in Game Maker but... It would be painful)

Anyway, I tried way too many different ways without success, the model has IK bones which made me use bonepose.matrix to get the "real morphs", seems the parents are applying weird transformations for their children, all the bones use Quaternions except the root bone which uses Euler XYZ.

Using matrix_basis also fails by rotating to different angles, I need to check more about it.

[image: Bugged]

[image: Correct]